# Mongo doesn't match string with strange space characters

Tags: mongodb, encoding

I have two documents with a field named `contact_name` that contains the exact first name and last name but the space that is separating them seems to be different. 
The input could be from any keyboard/device since it comes through an API(iOS app, android app, browser). 
MongoDb version is 3.0.3

How could I make Mongo match any type of space?

One space is encoded 20 and one is a0

Comment: Most model two fields instead of one.

Answer (score 1):

you could use regex pattern

```
 db.collection.find({contact_name: {$regex:/firstName.*lastName/})
```

and maybe this is better for matching blank spaces(not easy for me to test if `\s` will match `0xa0` with mongodb, but it promised to be working just as well)

```
 db.collection.find({contact_name: {$regex:/firstName\s+lastName/})
```

Comment: Use regex in your Mongo query.